# How to download remote files in Java

Tags: java, networking, server, remote-access, remote-server

There are some posts regarding how to *read from*/*write to* a file in a remote system. However, I haven't found one useful to my purposes and I hope you can help me out.

So far, I have a java program that can connect to a server using sockets. The remote system (server) is not in the LAN which I think makes it more complicated to access files in that computer. The purpose of my "networking program" is to download files that are in the remote server and I can achieve this by copying bytes of the file once I have reached it, but I don't know how to "navigate" through the directories of the server. The only thing I've done so far is to connect to it.

The remote server runs on Linux. I'm trying to find out how to do this and I came across with JSch. I have not read too much about it but I would like to ask you if this is possible with JSch or what is the solution you would use.

Answer (score 1):

JSch can surely work.

Refer this: [File download](http://kodehelp.com/java-program-for-downloading-file-from-sftp-server/)

Comment: do you recommend to use JSch or Apache Commons Net?

Comment: Use JSch if you are planning to use SFTP.